# Create NSArray of a folder subpaths

Tags: iphone, objective-c, directory, nsarray, nsdocument

Is there a core method to create an array representation of a folder?
I mean something like

```
[
folder1[
    001.jpg,
    002.jpg
    ],
folder2[
    subfolder1[
        001.jpg
        002.jpg
        ],
    ]
folder3[
    001.jpg
    ]
]
```

I'm using subpathsAtPath to get an array of a single folder: should I loop across all subfolders or is there a smarter way?

Answer (score 0):

NSArray* fileNames = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&outError];

Answer (score 0):

You may be better of with enumeratorAtPath:, you can then enumerate through decedents and use NSDirectoryEnumerator to get level.